# ValueError Mixing apples and oranges: my.model() < False - Odoo v8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I have this wizard button, which saves fields as records on a table:

```
@api.multi
def save_data(self, vals):
    vals = {
        self.name : 'name',
        self.date_production : 'date_production',
        self.type_prod : 'type_prod',
        self.product_id : 'product_id',
        self.qty_available : 'qty_available',
        self.print_order2 : 'print_order2',
        self.name_block : 'name_block',
        }
    self.env['bsi.production.order'].create(vals)
```

This is a step by step wizard, these are the original fields on my model:

```
class bsi_production_order(models.Model):
_name = 'bsi.production.order'
_inherit = ['mail.thread','text.paper','book.binding', 'book.block','book.edge','book.edition','book.size','cut.off','end.paper','job.rate','paper.master','printing.code', 'mrp.worksheet.contract', 'work.order.isbn.code', 'product.template'] 

@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    if vals.get('name', 'New') == 'New':
        vals['name'] = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('bsi.production.order') or '/'
    return super(bsi_production_order, self).create(vals)

    name = fields.Char('Reference', required=True, index=True, copy=False, readonly='True', default='New')
    date_production = fields.Date(string="Production Date")
    type_prod = fields.Selection([
        ('budgeted','Budgeted'),
        ('nonbudgeted','Non Budgeted'),
        ('direct','Direct Order'),
    ], string='Type of Order', index=True,  
    track_visibility='onchange', copy=False,
    help=" ")
    product_id = fields.Many2one('product.template', string="Product")
    qty_available = fields.Float(string="Qty Available", related="product_id.qty_available")
    production_qty = fields.Float(string="Qty to produce")
    print_order2 = fields.Many2one('bsi.print.order', string="Print Order")
    book_block = fields.Many2one('book.block', )
    name_block = fields.Selection(string="Code", related="book_block.name_block", store=True)
```

When I try to save the records from the wizard it says:

```
    ValueError

Mixing apples and oranges: bsi.print.order() < False
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

This is definitely something related to `Many2one` and/or `One2many` fields, I've got another error like this with another field, which is a `Many2one` type of field.

There is also something curious that might have something to do with it, and is the fact that when I save a `bsi.production.order` in the traditional form way, not by wizard, the Many2one `related` fields are shown, but when I save the new record, they just got empty somehow, it's like it doesn't save them for some reason, I've added the `store=True` flag to them, but still the same behaviour.

**Second Edit**

Full stack trace:

```
2017-08-26 22:42:46,786 1688 ERROR bsi_def openerp.http: Exception during JSON request handling.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 546, in _handle_exception
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 583, in dispatch
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 319, in _call_function
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\service\model.py", line 118, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 316, in checked_call
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 812, in __call__
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 412, in response_wrap
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 948, in call_button
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 936, in _call_kw
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 268, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 399, in old_api
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\openerp\addons\mrp_worksheet_contract\models\models.py", line 780, in save_data
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 266, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\openerp\addons\mrp_worksheet_contract\models\models.py", line 476, in create
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 266, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\openerp\addons\mrp_worksheet_contract\models\models.py", line 15, in create
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 266, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 508, in new_api
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\openerp\addons\product\product.py", line 742, in create
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 268, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 372, in old_api
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\openerp\addons\mrp_work_order_isbn\models\models.py", line 28, in create
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 266, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 508, in new_api
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\openerp\addons\mail\mail_thread.py", line 381, in create
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 268, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 372, in old_api
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 4101, in create
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 5608, in __lt__
except_orm: ('ValueError', 'Mixing apples and oranges: bsi.print.order() < False')
```

Comment: Full stack trace please

Comment: Hi, added the full stack trace, see my edit, Thank You

Comment: The problem comes with ´Many2one´ fields only, I think it has something to do with ´self.env´ calling to my model, which actually creates a new record in my table, there's some conflict with Many2one fields for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First when you define a dictionary key comes first

```
             'name' : self. name
```

and for many2one pass the id value because it's an object

```
             'product_id' : self.product_id.id
```

Hope this fix your problem because it's the first time i have ever seen this error.

One thing always check your field first because if product_id is empty you have an error lkke bool has no attribute id

Comment: Super awesome! Thank You very much